# Has anyone successfully built Boost libraries using Apple's new ARM DTK?

Tags: boost, build, arm, xcode12, macos-big-sur

With the Apple ARM DTK released only three weeks ago, has anyone had any experience building Boost 1_73_0 or the 1_74_0 beta on the ARM DTK?  If so, are there any special build considerations?

NOTE: the version of clang with Xcode 12 is:  clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.22.19)

To be clear -- this was NOT something I could "research", as I do NOT have a DTK and won't for a while.  It's a PERFECTLY reasonable question to be asking here.

Comment: Did you find any solution?